# Extract a part of regular expression java

Tags: java, string, expression, extract

I need help to know how to extract just a part of regular expression in Java with reference.
Example: I have a text like:

"Jean Moulin - Porte d'Orléans - Paris 14e 
Jean Moulin. Apartment 37 m² renovated in 2013. Materials and quality services. Large living room with kitchen, separate bedroom area, dressing room, toilet / sink, large shower, toilet with sink and washing machine equipment, marble floor, double glazed window sound. Quiet, functional, spacious. On the first floor with open views, elevator, guards. Furniture and equipment new appliances. 
€ 310,000.

Rooms: 2 
Bedrooms: 1 
Surface: 37 m²
"

And I want only to take the number of rooms with the mark "rooms" How I can do?
I know just that:

```
Pattern p;
Matcher m;
p= Pattern.compile("Rooms: +[0-9]");
```

but I want only the number, I want to delete "Rooms: " from the result.

And the 2nd question, How to take the name of the city with a regular expression, because if I have a lot of text with different name of city: like Paris, London, Lyon, Rome etc... How I can do to make one regular expression that does this?

Comment: Use lookbehind to match but not extract

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want only the number, I want to delete "Rooms: " from the result.

Use [Matcher#group()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) to get the matched group that is enclosed inside the Parenthesis `()`that is used to enable grouping of regex phrases.

Here `group(1)` returns the `(\\d+)` if found.

Sample code:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Rooms:\\s+(\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Rooms: 2 Bedrooms: 1 Surface: 37 m² ");

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // output 2 only
    }
```

Please have a look at [Java Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) where all the pattern are explained in details. Find sample code here on [Java Tutorials - Quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

Comment: You probably wanted to place `+` inside group. Otherwise group will contain only last matched digit.

Comment: Thank youuu for your answer so fast!!! It works!!
And for the 2nd question, do you have an idea?

Comment: Get the word after two hyphens. You can use `string.indexOf('-')`.

Comment: Sometimes name of the city can have more than one word like New York so additional rule is needed like end it before first space and digit like in case `Paris 14e` we want to stop before `space` and `1`.

Comment: @Pshemo I don't understand "+ inside group"?? What it means?
Beacause for the surface if I did the method of "Braj" I have only the numer 3, so how I can have 37 m²?
And yes I agree with you for the city which have more than one word, but how to take it? Beacause I can't put in my regex all the name of city...

Comment: @user3590882 I mean `(\\d+)` instead of `(\\d)+`. First example of group can hold one or more digits, second group can only store one digit and will update its value with each matched digit. In other words in case of `543` firs group will match it as `(543)` and second will try to do something like `(5)(4)(3)` and each time it will match new value old one will be replaced by it which will leave you only `3` as match from this group.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for participating in the conversation.

Comment: Ooooh so goooood it works!! Thank you guys!!
Now I need to get the name of city...

Comment: @Braj You are welcome :) Anyway I think OP understand what `+` means since it was used in regex in question. OP probably didn't understand my phrase "+ inside group" which referred to: `(\\d)+` here `+` is "outside" of group; `(\\d+)` now `+` is "inside".

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceAll()` with a back reference to extract it in one line:

```
String rooms = input.replaceAll("(?is).*\\brooms\\s+(\\d+).*", "$1");
```